# \SetTracking seems to have no effect

Tags: microtype

From the documentation:

```
\SetTracking [〈options〉] {〈set of fonts〉} {〈tracking amount〉}
```

I have tried all kinds different incarnations of this command (many of them copied verbatim from online), to no avail. I am fairly new to LaTeX, so perhaps I am just using it wrong?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding = *}{4}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\raggedright

\usepackage[paperwidth=2.125in,paperheight=2.75in,top=.2in,bottom=.2in,left=.25in,right=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tiny
Here is my text. \textbf{I occasionally use bold text} For whatever reason, size tiny "stretches out" my letters. I am trying to make it look good again.
\end{document}
```

The four in the curly braces is a number I have replaced with huge numbers and small numbers, and I can't seem to get it to effectuate any change on the output.

This code generates a warning which I really just don't understand:

```
Package microtype Warning: tracking amount list `book.tex/6' will override list
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `\tiny` selects the optical font for that size, the font is designed that way.

Comment: The warning just reminds you that you have overridden the default and has no consequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letters appear to be “stretched out” because the font used with `\tiny` is so designed; the warning is just a reminder that you are overriding the default. But the main point is that tracking must be explicitly enabled with `\lsstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  paperwidth=2.125in,
  paperheight=2.75in,
  top=.2in,
  bottom=.2in,
  left=.25in,
  right=.2in
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding = *}{1000}

\raggedright

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tiny\lsstyle
Here is my text. \textbf{I occasionally use bold text} For 
whatever reason, size tiny "stretches out" my letters. I am
trying to make it look good again.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. I will need to learn what \pagestyle and \lsstyle do. Thank you!